# Can QWidget detect mouse events on behalf of a QLineEdit?

Tags: pyqt, mouseevent, qlineedit

I have a QWidget that contains QLabels and QLineEdits side by side.

When I click on a QLabel, I can use the mousePressEvent in QWidget. But when I click on QLineEdit, I can't detect the mousePressEvent in QWidget - only in the QLineEdit. I think that it is related to how QLineEdit works - I don't know the way to get mouse events within the whole region.

**EDIT**:

[image]

I have made a custom channel box for Maya like above. I try to select multiple channels by dragging the mouse. But as I mentioned, in the QLineEdit regions I can't do this.

```
class channelWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
  def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(channelWidget, self).__init__(parent)
    self.resize(180, 20)        
    self.setMinimumSize(180, 20)
    self.setMaximumHeight(20)
    self.attr_label = QtGui.QLabel(self)
    self.attr_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(5, 0, 110, 20))
    self.attr_label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight|QtCore.Qt.AlignTrailing|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
    self.value_field = focusLineEdit(self)
    self.value_field.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 0, 60, 20))
    self.value_field.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft|QtCore.Qt.AlignLeading|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
    self.value_field.setValidator(QtGui.QDoubleValidator())
```

Each element consists of a QLabel and a QLineEdit.

```
class channelContainerWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
  def updateChannel(self, node="", attrList=[]):
    _l = self.channel_layout
    _list = []
    for w in [_l.itemAt(i).widget() for i in range(_l.count()) if _l.itemAt(i).widget()]:
      if w in self._selectList: _list.append( str( w.attr_label.text() ) )
        sip.delete(w)

    _selList = []
    for _id, at in enumerate(attrList):
      _item = channelWidget(self)
      _item.attr_label.setText(at)
      _item.value_field.setText(value)
      _l.insertWidget(_id, _item)
```

And the containing widget works as above. When I click on QLabel region, I can get mouse events, but when I click on the QLineEdit region, I can't.

Comment: question is not clear, have you tried SIGNALS and SLOTS ?

Comment: @AmazingSixty Yes, I tried with SIGNAL and SLOT method. But, it doesn't work as I wish on `mouseMoveEvent()` :(

Comment: Let me get this straight ? Do you want something to happen when a user clicks on the QLineEdit ?

Comment: Paste the code in your question, so it would be easy for us to understand

Comment: Shameless plug: In case you end up wanting more detailed information on this process, I actually create a Maya ChannelBox in my [PyQt for Maya video tutorial](http://www.cmivfx.com/tutorials/view/498/PyQt4+UI+Development+for+Maya) :-)

Comment: Also, why use `sip.delete(w)` instead of `w.deleteLater()`?

Answer (score 3):

If you are watching the `mousePressEvent()` from the main widget containing the layout, the reason you are seeing clicks for the `QLabel` is because by default a `QLabel` ignores the `mousePressEvent` and allows it to bubble up to the next parent. Events propagate upward from child->parent.

A `QLineEdit` however does need to accept and use a mouse press, to handle focus and other various actions common to a line edit widget.

So really what might be a good option for you is to use an [event filter](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qobject.html#eventFilter). This will allow your main widget to watch events for other widgets, without having to subclass the `QLineEdit` and implement the `mousePressEvent`

In this example, it simply watches for any member of the layout and a mouse press, and prints, then does the default action to not change anything:

```py
class Widget(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Widget, self).__init__()

        self.layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)

        self.label = QtGui.QLabel("Label")
        self.line = QtGui.QLineEdit()

        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.line)        

        # have this widget (self) watch events for these    
        self.label.installEventFilter(self)
        self.line.installEventFilter(self)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        print "Main Widget Mouse Press"
        super(Widget, self).mousePressEvent(event)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        # you could be doing different groups of actions
        # for different types of widgets and either filtering
        # the event or not.
        # Here we just check if its one of the layout widgets
        if self.layout.indexOf(obj) != -1:
            if event.type() == event.MouseButtonPress:
                print "Widget click", obj
                # if I returned True right here, the event
                # would be filtered and not reach the obj,
                # meaning that I decided to handle it myself

        # regardless, just do the default
        return super(Widget, self).eventFilter(obj, event)
```

When you test this code, you will see that clicking the label causes both a print in the main widget and its event filter. But clicking on the line edit causes only the event filter print statement, because the default `mousePressEvent` accepts it and does not propagate it further.