# Pyqt 5 how to make QLineEdit clickable

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I just wonder how to make a `QLineEdit` clickable because I want when the `QLineEdit` is clicked to clear the line's text.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can QWidget detect mouse events on behalf of a QLineEdit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13465329/can-qwidget-detect-mouse-events-on-behalf-of-a-qlineedit)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Click Event of QLineEdit in QT?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452077/how-to-get-click-event-of-qlineedit-in-qt)

Comment: It is quite a trivial thing to do. If all you need is clearing the line edit, reimplment `mousePressEvent` or `mouseReleaseEvent` in your custom class and clear the text. Or use event filters as in the link given by @Ian above.

Comment: Use [setClearButtonEnabled](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#clearButtonEnabled-prop).

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Code to make `QLineEdit` clickable :

```
class ClickableLabel(QLabel):

    clicked = pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self,name, widget):
        super().__init__(name, widget)
    def mousePressEvent(self, QMouseEvent):
        self.clicked.emit()
```

Comment: It says `QLabel` there in the code, not `QLineEdit`

Answer (score 0):

Here is my 2 cents...

Definition :

```
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLineEdit
    from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
    from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal

    class cQLineEdit(QLineEdit):
        clicked= pyqtSignal()
        def __init__(self,widget):
            super().__init__(widget)
        def mousePressEvent(self,QMouseEvent):
            self.clicked.emit()
```

usage :

```
    self.cLE = cQLineEdit(self)
    self.cLE.setFixedWidth(20)
    self.cLE.move(10,200)
    self.cLE.clicked.connect(self.printText)

def printText(self):
    print("Yop,+++")
```

Hope this can help.